# Web Scraping using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to copy the list of hospitals, their addresses, and their phone numbers from [Catholic Health Initiatives](http://www.catholichealthinitiatives.org/landing.cfm?xyzpdqabc=0&id=39524&action=list).

The code I am using is:

```
# install.packages('rvest')
library('rvest')
htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.catholichealthinitiatives.org/landing.cfm?xyzpdqabc=0&id=39524&action=list")
chihtml <- html_nodes(htmlpage,".info , .address")
chi <- html_text(chihtml)
chi
library(stringr)

chi <- str_replace_all(chi, "[\r\n\t]" , "")
chi
```

and this is the heading result:

```
 [1] "CHI St. VincentTwo St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000F         501.552.4241"                                 
 [2] "Two St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000F 501.552.4241"                                                
 [3] "CHI St. Vincent Hot Springs300 Werner StreetHot Springs National Park,     AR 71913P 501.622.1000"                       
 [4] "300 Werner StreetHot Springs National Park, AR 71913P 501.622.1000"                                                  
 [5] "CHI St. Vincent InfirmaryTwo St. Vincent CircleLittle Rock, AR 72205P 502.552.3000F 501.552.4241"                    
 [6] "Two St. Vincent CircleLittle Rock, AR 72205P 502.552.3000F 501.552.4241"
```

I would like to remove the duplicated address found below the main line:

```
[1] "CHI EX:   St. VincentTwo St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000F            501.552.4241"                                 
## remove next line ##
[2] "Two St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P    501.552.3000F 501.552.4241"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `.info` *or* `.address` in `html_nodes`, depending on which you want:

```
chihtml <- html_nodes(htmlpage,".info")
chi <- html_text(chihtml, trim = TRUE)    # `trim = TRUE` to strip whitespace
head(chi)
# [1] "CHI St. Vincent\nTwo St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000F 501.552.4241"                      
# [2] "CHI St. Vincent Hot Springs\n300 Werner StreetHot Springs National Park, AR 71913P 501.622.1000"            
# [3] "CHI St. Vincent Infirmary\nTwo St. Vincent CircleLittle Rock, AR 72205P 502.552.3000F 501.552.4241"         
# [4] "CHI St. Vincent Morrilton\nFour Hospital DriveMorrilton, AR 72110P 501.977.2300F 501.977.2400"              
# [5] "CHI St. Vincent North\n2215 Wildwood AvenueSherwood, AR 72120P 501.977.2300F 501.977.2400"                  
# [6] "CHI St. Vincent Rehabilitation Hospital\n2201 Wildwood AvenueSherwood, AR 72120P 501.834.1800F 501.834.2227"
```

Comment: Thank you @alistaire! Is there any way to split up                                           [1] "CHI St. VincentTwo St. Vincent Cr.Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000F 501.552.4241"     by commas? Such as:                             [1] "CHI St. Vincent, Two St. Vincent Cr., Little Rock, AR 72205P 501.552.3000, F 501.552.4241"?    Sorry, I am pretty new to R and I am trying to do a side project at work.

Comment: The best way to do it is not to remove the `\n` (newline) characters, which tell you where line breaks should be, so you can call `strsplit(chi, '\n+')` to split it into a list with an element for each address, each of which is split. If it's messy (`trim = FALSE`), `strsplit` can actually do all your whitespace cleaning: `strsplit(chi, '[\n\r\t]+')`

Comment: That still doesn't split phones, faxes, and the final line of addresses with an extra, though. For that, you'll need some more serious regex.

Comment: More serious regex: `strsplit(trimws(chi), '[\n\r\t]+|(?<![A-Z])\\B(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z]\\.)\\b(?=[A-Z])', perl = TRUE)`

Comment: You have helped me immensely. Thanks a lot. Now time to learn this code and truly understand it! @alistaire

Comment: Just don't start with that last regex; it's sort of a mess! ...but it works.

Comment: I have written the following code to condense the different elements of the list into one but I can't seem to get it to apply to the rest of the list. `chi24_as_string = as.character(chi24[[1]])
if (length(chi24[1]) > 1) for (j in 2:length(chi24))   chi24_as_string = paste(chi24_as_string," ",as.character(chi24[[j]]),sep="")
chi24_as_string`                and the following is what is returned. `[1] "CHI St. Vincent"       "Two St. Vincent Cr."   "Little Rock, AR 72205" "P 501.552.3000" ` How can I change my for loop to return what is shown above for all 25 sections of the list?

Comment: My end goal is to get this list into correct format to change it into a legible data frame that contains `"CHI St. Vincent" "Two St. Vincent Cr." "Little Rock, AR 72205" "P 501.552.3000"` in row, for each (hospital) and then to export that to a csv. I'm not sure if i have gone about this the correct way, but it is one of the few ways I could think of. Thanks

Comment: It's a list. You can combine each into a single string with `lapply(chi_split, function(x){paste(x, collapse = ' ')})`, but that will make separating it into a data.frame much harder. The best way is probably to give each sub-element a name (Carefully! More regex probably necessary...), insert `NA`s as necessary, and once they all have the same elements, and then call `do.call(rbind, named_chi)` to combine into a data.frame.